# I have create 1 angular JS application on my localhost the project working fine.But while uploading on server it give me Unexpected token <

Tags: angularjs

[i have created one application, but while uploading on server, it give me error angular.js:9509 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js:2:2620](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxRs.png)

Comment: That sounds like some point of your code expects JSON response but HTML content (possibly error) is received. Possibly somewhere around `$http` or other service like that?

Comment: Actually i am trying to call $http from foreach loop. and i am getting that error. i have also check the response which  is also in json format

Comment: Feel free to share that portion of your code. This will enable others to help you, because currently your question sounds like: "I have a problem, but you will have to guess it by yourself." :)

Comment: thanks for your reply...i solved that problem

Comment: Please add your answer and accept it in order to close this topic.